# Unity Coroutine Yield seems to close coroutine every time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hey so I've been working on this damage over time code for quite awhile now, I've used MANY online resources, and I have tons of iterations of trying this, and it hasn't worked, so I come here.
DISCLAIMER: My object does not get destroyed when yielding, it just hits the yield, and nothing happens.

```
if(CurrentStatus == Status.Burning && burning==false){
burning=true;
    StartCoroutine (DamageOverTimeCoroutine(100, 5));
    Debug.Log("what");
    burning = false;
    //CurrentStatus = Status.Empty;
```

}

```
public IEnumerator DamageOverTimeCoroutine(float damageAmount, float duration){
        float amountDamaged = 0;
        float damagePerLoop = damageAmount / duration;
        while (amountDamaged < damageAmount) {
            int numInt = (int)Math.Ceiling(damagePerLoop);
            enemyCurrentHealth -= numInt;
            var clone = (GameObject) Instantiate(damageNumber, this.gameObject.transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.zero));
            clone.GetComponent<FloatingNumbers> ().damageNumber = numInt;
            amountDamaged += damagePerLoop;
            yield return null;
            Debug.Log(amountDamaged);
        }
        if(amountDamaged>damageAmount){
            //StopCoroutine(DamageOverTimeCoroutine());
        }
        CurrentStatus = Status.Empty;
        burning=false;
    }
```

To reiterate, it does the damage, and then quits on the yield return, I've changed it from WaitSeconds just to see if it would work any other way, it does not. I've never had the Debug after the yield fire. Why is this happening?

Would be much appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: do you somewhere disable or destroy that object?

Comment: I know it's sort of off-topic, but as a side note `StopCoroutine(DamageOverTimeCoroutine());` won't work, even once your yielding works. When you call `StopCoroutine` you have to pass it the actual `IEnumerator` instance that you started the coroutine with (i.e. the one returned by the `DamageOverTimeCoroutine()` call in `StartCoroutine(DamageOverTimeCoroutine())`

Just letting you know because that problem has caused me many many issues in the past!

Comment: What did you pass in as the value for duration? I'm guessing you want duration to be seconds, yet here it's number of frames. Could it be that the value of duration is 1?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, the
var clone = (GameObject) Instantiate(damageNumber, this.gameObject.transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.zero));
clone.GetComponent ().damageNumber = numInt;

lines short circuted it without throwing a error. Odd, but it works now. Thanks for the input guys